# Cannot install wear application

Tags: wear-os, sony-smartwatch

I have an application I'm developing which has a Wear module and I'm having trouble getting it to install on the Wear device when I install the **release** version on the Mobile device. The Wear device ends up with the following log:

```
I/PkgMgrInstallUtil: Sending install intent to PackageInstaller Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSTALL_PACKAGE dat=content://com.google.android.clockwork.home.provider/host/app.id/wearable/app.id/apk typ=vnd.android.cursor.item/wearable_apk cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.wear.WearPackageInstallerService (has extras) } forapp.id
E/WearPkgInstallerService: Could not parse apk information for app.id
```

The android source points to [this](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_packageinstaller/blob/master/src/com/android/packageinstaller/PackageUtil.java) being the source of the error message "**Could not parse apk information for**":

```
public static PackageParser.Package getPackageInfo(File sourceFile) {
    final PackageParser parser = new PackageParser();
    try {
        PackageParser.Package pkg = parser.parseMonolithicPackage(sourceFile, 0);
        parser.collectManifestDigest(pkg);
        return pkg;
    } catch (PackageParserException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In addition, if I install a **debug** build directly to the Wear device (Sony SmartWatch3) the application does not start and I get a large warning message (below). That said, I can start the application just fine on the device from the application list and it works as expected.

> 04-14 16:57:50.761 10494 10494 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<< 04-14 16:57:50.773
>   10494 10494 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is OFF 04-14 16:57:50.789 10494
>   10494 W art     : 6f49f000-6fc40000 rw-p 00000000 103:00 127748
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.art 04-14 16:57:50.789
>   10494 10494 W art     : b1425000-b3304000 r--p 00000000 b3:1f 623
>   /system/framework/arm/boot.oat 04-14 16:57:50.789 10494 10494 W art
>   : b3304000-b4a61000 r-xp 01edf000 b3:1f 623
>   /system/framework/arm/boot.oat 04-14 16:57:50.789 10494 10494 W art
>   : b4a61000-b4a62000 rw-p 0363c000 b3:1f 623
>   /system/framework/arm/boot.oat 04-14 16:57:50.789 10494 10494 W art
>   : b4a62000-b4a7a000 r--p 007a1000 103:00 127748
>   /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.art 04-14 16:57:50.790
>   10494 10494 W art     : b4a7a000-b4a7b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [anon:linker_alloc_vector] 04-14 16:57:50.790 10494 10494 W art     :
>   b4a7c000-b4a7f000 r-xp 00000000 b3:1f 568
>   /system/lib/libsigchain.so 04-14 16:57:50.790 10494 10494 W art     :
>   b4a7f000-b4a80000 r--p 00002000 b3:1f 568
>   /system/lib/libsigchain.so 04-14 16:57:50.790 10494 10494 W art     :
>   b4a80000-b4a81000 rw-p 00003000 b3:1f 568
>   /system/lib/libsigchain.so 04-14 16:57:50.790 10494 10494 W art     :
>   b4a81000-b4eb3000 r-xp 00000000 b3:1f 473        /system/lib/libart.so
>   04-14 16:57:50.790 10494 10494 W art     : b4eb3000-b4eb4000 ---p
>   00000000 00:00 0

…

snip

…

> 04-14 16:57:50.809 10494 10494 W art
>   : b6f90000-b6f91000 r--p 0000e000 b3:1f 494
>   /system/lib/libcutils.so 04-14 16:57:50.809 10494 10494 W art     :
>   b6f91000-b6f92000 rw-p 0000f000 b3:1f 494
>   /system/lib/libcutils.so 04-14 16:57:50.809 10494 10494 W art     :
>   b6f92000-b6f93000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [anon:linker_alloc_vector] 04-14 16:57:50.809 10494 10494 W art     :
>   b6f93000-b6f94000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
>   [anon:linker_alloc_64] 04-14 16:57:50.809 10494 10494 W art     :
>   b6f94000-b6f95000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:linker_alloc]
>   04-14 16:57:50.962 10494 10494 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack
>   module (No such file or directory) 04-14 16:57:50.962 10494 10494 E
>   android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2 04-14
>   16:57:50.970 10494 10494 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio
>   DONE 04-14 16:57:51.032 10494 10494 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main
>   entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm 04-14 16:57:51.036 10494 10494 D
>   AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved it by creating a new project from scratch. The parsing made me think it might be an unexpected character somewhere.